# Change the function of the Delete/Backspace Key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a function that wraps selected text in a span when the delete key is pressed. The class of the span is red with a line-through, to show it's been "deleted."

CSS:

```
     .deleted {
     text-decoration:line-through;
     color:red;
       }
```

JavaScript:

```
    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
      (e) ? keycode = e.keyCode : keycode = event.keyCode;
      if (keycode == 8 || 46) {
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        span.className = "deleted";
        if (window.getSelection) {
           var sel = window.getSelection();
           if (sel.rangeCount) {
              var range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
              range.surroundContents(span);
              sel.removeAllRanges(); 
              sel.addRange(range);
              }
           } 
        }
     });
```

This is a `contenteditable` text, so when I press the delete key, naturally it deletes the selected text, but still creates the `<span>` element. Is there any way to disable the traditional function of the delete key so that the text remains but still wraps with the `<span>`?

Answer (score 1):

`e.preventDefault()` should work.

Also, you should use the `<del>` HTML element instead of `<span>` with a class attached.

Test out this testcase: https://jsfiddle.net/jdshq796/

Comment: Thanks! This works, except now my document is no longer `contenteditable`

Comment: Could I have the function make the `document.body.contentEditable='false'; document.designMode='off';` and then have it turn back on at the end of the function?

Comment: That should be possible - just test it and see? Using the information above, if you put those right after the e.preventDefault(); and at the end of the function, then you turn it back on again, that should, in theory work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the the default action of the event.

You need to add e.preventDefault() into your code that insure that default action of the event will not be triggered.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
      (e) ? keycode = e.keyCode : keycode = event.keyCode;
      if (keycode == 8 || 46) {
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        span.className = "deleted";
        if (window.getSelection) {
           var sel = window.getSelection();
           if (sel.rangeCount) {
              var range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
              range.surroundContents(span);
              sel.removeAllRanges(); 
              sel.addRange(range);
              }
           } 
        }
     });
```

Comment: This is the same solution that @junkfoodjunkie offered, but the only problem is that makes it so my document is no longer `contenteditable`